# Background fetch in IOS not working

Tags: codenameone

Back Ground fetch functionality with codenameone 1.5 release is working fine in Android devices and its not working in iOS devices. I have added "ios.background_modes=fetch" property also. Can you please help me on this.

Answer (score 3):

On iOS you'll have less control over background fetch than you do on Android.  The OS decides when it will allow you to perform a background fetch, and this depends on many factors.  On Android it works more like clock-work.  You specify the preferred interval, and it does an update on that interval (min 60 seconds I think).  On iOS it could be 10 minutes, or it could decide to disallow you altogether if your app has been taking too long on previous fetches.  Etc...

So given that information, what tests have you run to conclude that it is not working?